# Materializecss SideNav not closing with fluid width

Tags: jquery, materialize

I'm using Materializecss for a project rebuild and having a small issue with using a second sideNav.

I have one set for the menu (left aligned), and a second one to use for actions and other pages loaded with ajax (right aligned).

I'm trying to set the menuWidth based on the device size. EG Desktop 40%, else 90%.

But if I use a percentage for setting the width, I am unable to get the second sidebar to close on click.

Here is what I have:

```
$('.button-collapse-right').sideNav({
    menuWidth: '40%', // Default is 240
    edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin
    closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
});
```

My goal is:
1) to have 90% for smaller than desktop (992px) and 40% or 50% for desktop as the width for the second sideNav.
2) To have it close automatically if clicking on the overlay behind it
3) sideNav width should account for screen rotations and window size changes.

I was trying playing around with this function but couldn't get it to work for the above 3 goals.

```
var screenWidth = $(window).resize(function() {
    $("body").each(function(i,item){
        item = $(item);
        size = item.width() > '991' ? Math.floor(item.width() * 0.5) : Math.floor(item.width() * 0.9);
        console.log(size);
        return size;
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Haha and just a few minutes later I figure it out :P

Here's what I did if anyone else hits the same issue.

```
getPanelWidth = function() {
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    panelSize = screenWidth > '991' ? Math.floor(screenWidth * 0.5) : Math.floor(screenWidth * 0.9);
    console.log(panelSize);
    return panelSize;
};

$('.button-collapse-right').sideNav({
    menuWidth: getPanelWidth(), // Default is 240
    edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin
    closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
});
```